# os.path.join throws error 'type of argument must be str or bytes not TextIOWrapper'

Tags: python, json, operating-system, filesystems

I am trying to open and then read from a json-file (also later on do the same and dump some json data into the same file btw).

I simply wanted to use a variable for the file name so my code for this looks like this:

```
layout_file = 'layouts2.json'
try:
    filename = os.path.join(app.static_folder, layout_file)
    with open(filename) as layout_file:
        layouts = json.load(layout_file)
except:
    print("could not load layouts from config file")
```

Before my code looked like this and worked fine:

```
try:
    filename = os.path.join(app.static_folder, 'layouts2.json')
    with open(filename) as layout_file:
        layouts = json.load(layout_file)
except:
    print("could not load layouts from config file")
```

The error i get is `error 'type of argument must be str or bytes not TextIOWrapper'`. 
I don't really get what to do now, even this should be solvable pretty fast I guess.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `print(type(app.static_folder), app.static_folder)` : )

Comment: try `os.path.join(app.static_folder, layout_file)`

Comment: The codes look equivalent to me. I think we are not seeing the whole story here.

Comment: thanks for the answers, now I see what went wrong which was indeed stupid. The unfortunately named the variable for the name just like the one in the line with "with open(filename) as layout_file. So my code worked when I read the file in the beginning, as layout_file was still a string but at the second time when saving to the file afterwards, layout_file now was indeed not a string anymore :D

Comment: your right COVFEFE-19. I thought it would be enough to just post the code for reading the file not for writing to it afterwards. Only after that i realized that when reading everything went fine but afterwards when writing to the file, the problem started to appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the same variable, `layout_file`, for both the filename and the file handle.

In the code as written, that should work fine; however, if you do it in a loop or similar, you could end up with confusion between the two values. (If you use `mypy`, it will also complain.)

Use different variable names?

```
layout_filename = 'layouts2.json'
try:
    filename = os.path.join(app.static_folder, layout_filename)
    with open(filename) as layout_fh:
        layouts = json.load(layout_fh)
except:
    print("could not load layouts from config file")
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I just found that stupid mistake myself!